# Submit form via jquery modal to codeigniter controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I had a problem on submitting the form thru ajax jquery. My problem is, how to submit the jquery modal form to the codeigniter controller without refresh the page? at the same time, if the submitted data contains an error from codeigniter controller (validation), how the jquery will show the error message?

here is my code

**js script**

```
$(function() {

// Dialog
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 380,
    height:300,
    buttons: {
        'Save': function() {

  function submitForm(){

  $.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : 'http://localhost/hmvc/index.php/sysconfig/sysmenu/create',
  data : $('#menu_form').serialize(),
  success : function(data) {
      // Show OK message
      alert('ok');
  },
  error: function(error){
      // Show error message
      alert('error');
  }
});

return false;
}

        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    } 
 }); 

// Dialog Link
$('#dialog_link').click(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
}); 


});
```

**controller**

```
function _validate()
{
    $config = array(

                array(
                'field'=>'sysmenu_name',
                'label'=>'menu name',
                'rules'=>'trim|max_length[30]|htmlspecialchars|required|xss_clean'
                ),

                array(
                'field'=>'sysmenu_link',
                'label'=>'hyperlink',
                'rules'=>'trim|max_length[100]|htmlspecialchars|required|xss_clean'
                ),

                array(
                'field'=>'sysmenu_sequence',
                'label'=>'sequence',
                'rules'=>'trim|max_length[2]|htmlspecialchars|required|xss_clean'
                )

              );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error_msg">', '</div>');
}

function create()
{
  if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
  {
    $this->_validate();
    if($this->form_validation->run($this)==FALSE)
    {

           echo validation_errors();
    }


    } else {

        $menu_level = getValue_where('sysmenu_level',"sysmenu_id ='".$this->input->post('sysmenu_parent_id')."'",'base_sysmenu') + 1;

        $data = array(
                'sysmenu_name'=>$this->input->post('sysmenu_name'),
                'sysmenu_parent_id'=>$this->input->post('sysmenu_parent_id'),
                'sysmenu_link'=>$this->input->post('sysmenu_link'),
                'sysmenu_level'=>$menu_level,
                'sysmenu_sequence'=>$this->input->post('sysmenu_sequence')
                );

        $this->sysmenu_model->insert_menu($data);
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

**view**

```
<div id="dialog" title="<?php echo $this->lang->line('add_new_menu') ?>">
<div class="notice_msg"><?php echo $this->lang->line('compulsary'); ?></div><br />

<div class="errors"><!-- append the error message here --></div>

<?php echo form_open('','class=normal_form name=create_menu id=menu_form'); ?>
<label><?php echo $this->lang->line('menu_name'); ?></label><?php echo form_input('sysmenu_name'); ?>*<br />
<label><?php echo $this->lang->line('parent_menu'); ?></label><?php //echo form_input('sysmenu_parent_id'); ?><?php echo form_dropdown('sysmenu_parent_id', dropdown_where('sysmenu_id','sysmenu_name',"sysmenu_level = 1",'base_sysmenu'), ''); ?><br />
<label><?php echo $this->lang->line('menu_link'); ?></label><?php echo form_input('sysmenu_link'); ?>*<br />
<label><?php echo $this->lang->line('menu_sequence'); ?></label><?php echo form_input('sysmenu_sequence','','size=12, maxlength=2'); ?>*<br />
<label>&nbsp;</label><?php //echo form_submit('data',$this->lang->line('btn_save')); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using The Following Criteria.

In Controller Class Use a method to initial the View Page.

```
 public function CreateStudents() {

        $this->load->helper('form'); // include form helper

        $data['title'] = "Create Students Page"; //Title of the page

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data); // header
        $this->load->view('createstudents', $data);  // main content
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data); // footer
    }
```

Then create the Ajax Method. When submit the form this method is execute.

```
 public function CreateStudentsAjax() {

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('roll', 'Roll Number', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

        $this->welcome_model->InsertStudents();
        echo json_encode("Oks");
    } else {

        $data = array(
            'roll' => form_error('roll'),
            'name' => form_error('name'),
            'phone' => form_error('phone')
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

In View page add a Form

```
 <div id="message">


 </div> 

<?php echo form_open('welcome/CreateStudentsAjax'); ?>

    <label for="roll">Student Roll Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtRoll" value="" name="roll"/>

    <label for="Name">Students Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" value="" name="name"/>

    <label for="Phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtPhone" value="" name="phone"/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert New Students"  />

    <?php echo '</form>'; ?>
```

The Scripts is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('form').submit(function(){
                //alert('ok');      
                $.ajax({
                    url:this.action,
                    type:this.method,
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(data){
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                        if(obj['roll']!=null)
                        {                               
                            $('#message').text("");
                            $('#message').html(obj['roll']);
                            $('#message').append(obj['name']);
                            $('#message').append(obj['phone']);
                        }
                        else
                        {                               
                            $('#message').text("");
                            $('#message').html(obj); 
                        }

                    },
                    erro:function(){
                        alert("Please Try Again");
                    }                        
                });
                return false;
            });                        
        });

    </script>
```

This are all. Hope all enjoy the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit your form manually, and handle success/error inside the AJAX call.

Call a function like this from within `Save`:

```
function submitForm(){

 $.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : "sysconfig/sysmenu/create",
  data : postData, // Add your form data as inputname1=value1&inputname2=value2....
  success : function(data) {
   // Show OK message
  },
  error: function(error){
   // Show error message
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: so how i'm gonna show the validation error from the _validate method? sorry, i am new to jquery and CI

Comment: As @zaherg suggests, you'd better use a developer tool (the best one is Firebug for Firefox) and check what the server is returning. Once you know that, it will be easier to show the validation error.

Answer (score 0):

i will try to help but you will have to test it :

1. make sure that your form is return false, so that you will disable the default behavior of it ( as in http://s.zah.me/IouBgK but with some modification, add `return false;` and change the `data` to be `data : $('#yourformID').serialize(),` ).
2. you will have to check your submitted data in your controller to see if its an ajax request or not using the `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` and then you will echo the result of the validation or whatever your controller will do .

Comment: i already edit my question, the JS, controller and view has been updated. but the alert('error') still not appear. seems like the ajax doesn't post

Comment: your sending a json data type, but you handle it as a regular data, you will have to remove `dataType: 'json',` from your js .. ( and thats what i see in your code )

Comment: just remember to activate the developer tools in chrome or any other tool which can help you to see if the form is submitted or not, or if there is any other problem ..

Comment: I edit again my question follow your advices. and I'm using the firebug console. but nothing display in a console when i click the save button.

Comment: you should remove   `function submitForm(){` since your doing a function inside a function ?? plus the `}` after the `return false` and you never actually called the submitForm() function in your code, so you created it but never called it ..